# need help. rewriterule not working with /?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My URL is

```
http://example.com/?aff_id=username
```

and I want it like

```
http://example.com/?ap_id=username
```

I have tried all possible ways but no luck. If I removed `?` (question mark) it works but I want `?` in my URL. I know it is a regular expression so I tried to escape it but no luck.

Comment: I deleted "Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!" has nothing to do with the question. Please be so polite to read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), in particular the part about no chit-chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} aff_id=([\w]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?ap_id=%1 [R,L]
```

If you would like to make the redirect permanent, change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Yehhh...It worked.... :):)

Thank you sooo much Mike Rockett for your valuable time and answer. Thanks a lot :)